# Sencha Touch: How to refresh selectfield after store update

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to get a Sench selectfield to update dynamically.

Here is the code for the selectfield

```
items: [
        {
             xtype : 'container',
             flex: 1,
             id: 'introtext',
             html: '<p>Welcome your items above</p>'
        },
        {
             xtype : 'selectfield',
             store : companiesStore2,
             name : 'companies',
             id : 'companiesSelect',
                itemId: 'companySelect',
                valueField : 'companyname',
                displayField : 'companyname',
                style: 'overflow:hidden',
                listeners: {
                    change: function(field,value) {
                        getStats(value)
                    }
                }   
          },.......
```

When the page loads, the store has only one value. After login, more values are added to the store. `console.log(companiesStore2)` confirms that the new values are indeed being added to the store. However, they are not showing in my select field.

I have tried `companiesStore2.refresh()` but error message says the object has no method refresh.

Using sencha touch 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come upon an answer that seems to work for me.
After the data has changed, I re-assign the store to the selectfield using:

`Ext.getCmp('companiesSelect').setStore(companiesStore2)`

This seems to solve the problem that I was having.

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted any code to show how the store gets its new data.

2 things to try:

1. make the combo's `queryMode: 'local'`
2. when the store changes (add a listener e.g. `companiesStore2.on('datachanged', ...)`?), do this: `comboBox.bindStore(companiesStore2)`

Comment: Thanks for this. The listener works, but It seems that selectfields do not have method bindStore

Comment: 'datachanged' has been deprecated :-(